# How to execute a script in chrome extension? when the content is changed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to execute a chrome script,when the content of webpage is update (E.g like Facebook)

So what method I should use for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("body").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("something changed");
});
```

Note: `DOMSubtreeModified` is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified)

Comment: Where to place it?but involves jquery right? I am asking something involving chromes methods like  chrome.tabs.sendRequest

Comment: You'd put it in a content script.

Comment: You have said DOMSubtreeModified is deprecated right then what to use?

Comment: Don't really have any other options.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it with chrome.* API:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function(integer tabId, object changeInfo, Tab tab) {
     //your code
});
```

See here for documentation:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated

It should work for updates like (AJAX) requests etc...

Answer (score 0):

As `sachleen` said, you can use [`DOMSubtreeModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) listener

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", methodToRun);
```

Note that the [`Mutation Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events) are performance hogs which can't really be tamed well (they fire too often and slow down the page a lot). Therefore, they have been deprecated over a year ago and should be used only when really needed. However, they work.

If you want this for a Chrome extension, you could use the new and shiny [`Mutation Observers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers) from DOM Level 4 (follow the links there, they explain a lot!). Where `DOMSubtreeModified` fired a thousand times, `MutationObserver` fires only once with all the modifications contained and accessible.

Works for (as of 2012/06):

- Chrome 18+ (prefixed, `window.WebKitMutationObserver`)
- Firefox 14+ (unprefixed)
- WebKit nightlies